# Assigning a command to my NPM Package without installing globally

Tags: node.js, npm

Some NPM packages are installed into a project, you're then able to run them from your project `scripts`.

An example of this is [`webpack-dev-server`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server).

Once installed I just have to add:

```
"dev": "webpack-dev-server"
```

In my `package.json` scripts and it will launch `webpack-dev-server`.

How does this work? The command isn't globally installed, and yet my Node project knows that it's connected to the package that I have installed.

I've only been able to find information about adding my commands to the `bin` property within my package's `package.json`, but that won't work unless the package is installed globally.

How do I achieve this? Is there official documentation somewhere that I haven't been able to find?

Comment: You have the `global` and `local` install. And you need to see if your environment is `dev` or `prod`. If you trying to install in `prod`, the package marked on `dev` will not be installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you got it right, but you are missing tiny thing...

each package can declare a binary. as you said, this is done in the [`bin`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin) property of the `package.json`

> on install, npm will symlink that file into prefix/bin for global installs, or ./node_modules/.bin/ for local installs.

this is exactly what [`webpack-dev-server`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/package.json#L5) does. its binary is being installed within `./node_modules/.bin/`.

due to the convention, npm\npx is able to find the binary and execute it.

in your application, you can utilize this behavior; and any package that will be dependent on your package will be able to execute your package binary.

if you want to provide an argument to the run script, do it like so

```sh
npm run webpack-dev-server -- --version
```

Comment: Oh! That makes sense. I had already locally installed the project so it hadn't installed the commands inside `./node_modules/.bin`.

Comment: Just one last question. It seems that even on fresh install of my package, scripts that are not inluded inside `bin` are being added. What's causing this?

Comment: Nevermind, looks like it was just a cache problem. Thank you for your help!